# php laravel - try-catch not working

Tags: php, try-catch, laravel

my api controller:

```
$POST /api/member/logout

public function post_logout(){
    try{
        member::logout();
        return Response::json([], 200);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        print_r($e);
        return Response::json($e, 500);
    }
}
```

and my model

```
public static function logout(){
    if(!Auth::check()){
        throw new Exception('not_logged');
    }

    Auth::logout();
}
```

It is returning status 200 but never ends loading (18.3mb loaded and counting...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing Exception object before json response with status 500, so PHP automatically sends response with status code 200.

As for huge never-ending response, I'm not sure since I don't know Laravael at all, but I suspect, that somewhere you are (or this framework is) dumping an object that references itself.